# Running Total omitting repeat values

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report that shows various cost data for distinct records. The records are cars that have sold at auction. I have many running total fields and they are working properly except in the cases where there are repeat values. These are not duplicate values in the true sense, they are distinct cars that occasionally have the same monetary value. For instance, car 1001 sold at auction for $500, car 1005 also sold for $500. In the running total, only one instance of $500 is being included. I checked the formatting and "Suppress Duplicates" is NOT checked.

Comment: how is your running total set up? What is the evaluation and reset set at?

Comment: Evaulate: on change of field

Comment: Reset is set to:   never

Comment: on change of which field? Should be car?

Comment: Thanks CoSpringsGuy. I had it set to the wrong field. It's working properly now.